# Smarty passing data from controller to view and displaying data

Tags: php, smarty

I'm getting data from database with this function which is working fine.

```
static function dohvatiSveOlijeku($id){
    $baza = new Baza();

    $upit = "SELECT * FROM lijek WHERE status = 1 and lijek.id = " . $id;

    $rez = $baza->selectDB($upit);
    if($rez->num_rows == 0){
        return null;
    }else{
        $red = $rez->fetch_assoc();
        return $red;
    }
}
```

and this is my controller which is using parameter *id* to get data from model...

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
$LijekSve = Lijek::dohvatiSveOlijeku($_GET['id']);
}


$Smarty->assign('lijek', $LijekSve);
$Smarty->display('view/lijek.tpl');
```

and this is a view which is presenting given data

```
{foreach from=$lijek item =lijekpodaci}
    <div>
        <p>{$lijekpodaci.cijena} kuna</p>
    </div>
{/foreach}
```

For each item in table I get this error

```
 Illegal string offset 'cijena' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ljekarna\smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php(171) : eval()'d code on line 69 1 kuna
```

I also tried this, but the same error shows

```
{$lijekpodaci['cijena']}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not try using a conditional statement to check if the $lijek Array is empty before you loop? Here's how:

```
    <?php
        // INITIALIZE $LijekSve TO AN EMPTY ARRAY JUST IN CASE $_GET['id'] ISN'T SET
        $LijekSve       = array();      
        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
            $LijekSve   = Lijek::dohvatiSveOlijeku($_GET['id']);
        }

        $Smarty->assign('lijek', $LijekSve);
        $Smarty->display('view/lijek.tpl');
    ?>
```

**TEMPLATE**

```
        {if !empty($lijek) }
            {foreach from=$lijek item =lijekpodaci}
                <div>
                    <p>{$lijekpodaci.cijena} kuna</p>
                </div>
            {/foreach}
        {/if}
```